# SFC couldn't restore some files

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, sfc

Have ran `SFC /SCANNOW` and it said that found some corrupted files but was unable to restore some of them. Neither number of found or restored files provided.

Output said to look for file windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log which contains 29000 of lines approx.

How to figure out the scale of the problem roughly?

Comment: Determine which files are corrupted..But you really should just install Windows it really does sound like its beyond repair.  **You can also post the log itself, and use DISM, but every single one of your problems is because of this corruption.**

Comment: How to determine, which files are corrupted?

Comment: Read through the log and find the errors

Comment: have you used DISM? Was it able to fix all issues?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.x you should run the [new DISM command to repair files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) which is much better compared to sfc:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

It will download the missing or corrupted files from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `sfc /scannow` is that Windows is still "online" and files that can't be repaired are still in use.

This is where a WinPE disk can come in handy because you can use DISM to do an offline check of the system image. Look up Windows 8 dism offline check.

Comment: Can I do repair if plug this disk into another PC?

Comment: You need to use a WinPE disk

Comment: If you connect the disk to another Win 8.1 machine that has the WAIK kit installed then, yes, you can. Bit more technical but can be done.